# Inserting data into database in one record from multiple forms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have four forms in the same application and I have a Ms access database that has to be inserted with data from the app through out three of the forms and also the data has to be inserted in one record but different fields.

Like this:
form1 insert data into five fields,
form2 has to store the data in field six,
form3 has to store the data in field seven,
All the above inserts must happen in one record.

I have written the insert code in form1 and form2 but what happens is this: the user input is inserted nicely into the database for the first five fields, that's for form1, and the problem is, when I navigate to form2, the data is inserted into the right field but wrong record (that is, next record).I haven't written any code that might do what I wish for, just need guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a where condition when opening the form in order to open the form on the right record:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEmployee", WhereCondition:="EmployeeID=3"
```

Of course each record needs primary key that uniquely identifies each record (`EmployeeID` in my example).

If you open the form from another form that diaplays the same record you will have to take the record id from this form:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEmployee", WhereCondition:="EmployeeID=" & Me!EmployeeID
```

---

If you only allow the user to edit this one record, it is a good idea to set the form properties like this:

In the Format tab:

```
Allow Form View = Yes
Allow Datasheet View = No
Allow PivotTable View = No
Allow PivotChart View = No
Allow PivotChart View = No
Record Selectors = No       (not necessary since we allow only one record)
Navigation Buttons = No     (not necessary since we allow only one record)
```

In the Data tab:

```
Allow Filters = No
Allow Edits = Yes
Allow Deletions = No
Allow Additions = No
Data Entry = No       (If set to yes this opens the form on a new empty record)
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier, but...my database auto creates the ID and the app can be used so many times, so am not sure which unique variable to use so the insertion can continue  to store in the same record.

Comment: You said that you are entering five fields in `form1` and then open `form2` to continue entering other fields of the same record. If `form1` is bound to the table, set `Dirty = False` before openening the second form. This stores the record. Now you can access the auto-id field like this: `Me!NameOfIDField`. But you should consider to use a `TabControl` with several tab pages instead of using several forms.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, that's it, mission accomplished.